# What is the difference between the structure of nitrito-O and nitrito-N?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, nomenclature, coordination-compounds, molecular-structure, isomers

I am preparing for chemistry olympiad and I am stuck nitrito-*O* and nitrito-*N*. Can anyone explain difference between the structure of nitrito-*O* and nitrito-*N* or point a resource which is suitable for a beginner?

Comment: http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/Core/Inorganic_Chemistry/Coordination_Chemistry/Isomers/Structural_Isomers_in_Inorganic_Molecules#Linkage_Isomerism or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linkage_isomerism

Comment: Please specify your question. Are you having trouble with resonance structures, o-,m-,p- naming or sigma and pi- electron-withdrawing/donating effects?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The last letter of nitrite-*O* and nitrite-*N* depicts the atom which is attached to the other atom. This phenomenon is called [linkage isomerism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linkage_isomerism) and is an important concept in both organic and inorganic chemistry.

#### Inorganic chemistry

[image: pentaamminenitrito-N-cobalt(III)]

This complex exhibits linkage isomerism which results in two possible ways of attachment of ligand to the central atom. First one, the $\ce{NO2}$ ligates with (attaches to) the central atom through the **nitrogen atom** and thus is called pentaammine**nitrito-*N***-cobalt(III) chloride and the second one,  $\ce{NO2}$ ligates with the central atom through the **oxygen atom** and thus is called pentaammine**nitrito-*O***-cobalt(III) chloride. In this case, $\ce{NO2}$ is called ambident ligand and is represented as **nitrito-κ-*N*** and **nitrito-κ-*O***, replacing the old system of trivial names such as nitro and nitroso.

#### Organic chemistry

Alkyl nitrite forms two isomers: $\ce{RNO2}$ (called alkyl **nitrite-*N***) and $\ce{R-O-N=O}$ (called alkyl **nitrite-*O***).For preparation of these two isomers, see [Reaction of an alkyl halide with silver nitrite](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/50188).