# Structure of AgNO2 and AgONO

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, nitro-compounds

We had a discussion in class today about the substitution reaction of RX with AgNO2 and KNO2. Pretty unimportant, since those seem just fine. But there were 2 arguments.

The root problem was, that we couldn't figure out what the structure of AgNO2 was.

Online, almost all images depict the structure as an Ag atom bonded with the Oxygen atom of the ONO group for instance... [image]

The question raised was whether this is AgNO2 or whether should this be called AgONO.
In my opinion, the true structure for AgNO2 should be

[image]

except there should be Ag instead of R.

The structure in the first image, according to me should be that of AgONO.

Hence when talking about reaction with AgNO2, N would be bonded to Ag, making only oxygen available to attack RX, hence forming RONO as a product.

However, some argue that the first image does indeed depict the structure of AgNO2, hence it is in fact Oxygen that is bonded to Ag, making Nitrogen available for attack and hence forming RNO2 (second img) as a product. In fact, many resources online as say this as well, which as per my knowledge is incorrect.

Which structure for AgNO2 is correct? If it is the first one, what then would be different in AgONO if there is any difference between the two.

As a bonus question, do tell the products for both the reactions, i.e. RX with AgNO2 as well as KNO2.

I guess I do understand that Ag compound, regardless of which one it is would not entirely dissociate as is the case with AgCN group. Hence, whichever atom is bonded to Ag, the R group would be attached to the other atom that is available. that is... if Ag is attached to N, RONO would be formed whereas if Ag is attached to O, RNO2 would be formed. KNO2 confuses me a little too. Since there is a complete dissociation, we have the NO2- group. In this case, would it be the Nitrogen atom that would attach to the R group (since it is less electronegative and would thus donate electrons more easily) or would it be the Oxygen atom that would attach (since it simply has more available electrons to form bonds)? In other words, for KNO2 or KONO, whichever one it is, would the product be RONO or RNO2?

Comment: Alkyl nitrites (R-ONO) can be made by the reaction of alcohols with sodium nitrite (NaNO2) and acid (forming nitrous acid HNO2) see http://orgsyn.org/demo.aspx?prep=CV2P0108

Comment: The nitrite ion is ambident; alkyl halides react specifically with silver nitrite to form both nitroalkanes and alkyl nitrite esters. https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/ja01641a029

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between the structure of nitrito-O and nitrito-N?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/55300/what-is-the-difference-between-the-structure-of-nitrito-o-and-nitrito-n)

Comment: Based on all the answers and comments, Here's the picture I have in my mind :
As per Saytzeff rule, no bond is completely covalent or completely ionic. In case of RNO2, the bond is predominantly covalent whereas, with K and Ag, the NO2 bond is predominantly ionic. Thus in RNO2, there is a fair possibility of NO2 acting as an ambidentate ligand, both NO2 and ONO structures are possible.

NO2- is a polyatomic ion; its charge distribution has been controversial but largely, at least in case of metals like Ag, Oxygen is what interacts during bonding.

Comment: --continued--
KNO2 completely dissociates into K+ and NO2-, making Oxygen available to make bonds with R, reacting with RX to form RONO.

AgNO2 however doesn't dissociate as much due to it being slightly more covalent. Thus, while oxygen is still loosely bonded to Ag+ due to Electrostatic attractions as part of NO2- group, Nitrogen, with its lone pair, is the next best nucleophile to interact with the R group in RX, forming RNO2.

Comment: @Maddy this seems about right.

Comment: I'm glad! Thank you, everyone, for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reference[[1]](https://doi.org/10.1021/ja01641a029) mentioned in the comments shows that the reaction of silver nitrite with alkyl halides produces predominantly the nitro compound, $\ce{R–NO2}$ with over $80$% yield. This suggests that regardless of its crystal structure in the solid, silver nitrate in organic-solvent solution has the structure

$\ce{Ag–O–N=O}$

with the nitrite group covalently bonded through oxygen. This structure is also given in [this answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/50196/17175) by Nilay Ghosh. It renders the lone pair on the less electronegative nitrogen atom as the primary nucleophilic site, producing the nitro compound as the major product.

The bonding to oxygen in the molecular/monomeric structure may be explained in terms of ligand-field theory. The nitrite-ion ligand is a sigma donor primarily through the oxygen atoms, which formally share the negative charge, and a pi acceptor through the nitrogen atom where a relatively low-lying pi antibonding orbital has most of its electron density (similar to the molecular-orbital structure of ozone or sulfur dioxide). In many complexes, such as [cobaltinitrite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potassium_hexanitritocobaltate(III)), the pi-acceptor interaction dominates and coordination through the nitrogen is favored; but in Group 11 cations like $\ce{Ag^+}$ the $d$ electrons are effectively sunk to the core and the pi interaction is poor. So the silver coordinates predominantly by sigma bonding through the better sigma donor (oxygen), neutralizing the formal charge and leaving the nitrogen as the next best nucleophile for reaction with the alkyl halide.

**Reference**

1. Nathan Kornblum, Bernard Taub, and Herbert E. Ungnade (1954). "The Reaction of Silver Nitrite with Primary Alkyl Halides". *J. Am. Chem. Soc.* **76**, 12, 3209–3211.
   https://doi.org/10.1021/ja01641a029

Comment: okayy! that was really helpful and detailed. So in a nutshell, you suggest that oxygen and nitrogen are preferable at 2 distinct levels of pi interactions. In case of Ag, oxygen is more involved in the interaction as compared to nitrogen, making nitrogen the next best nucleophile available to react with the alkyl halide. Yeah? How about KNO2? I believe in that case, the covalent character is too weak that even the oxygen is available for the reaction with alkyl halide. Right?

Comment: Yes, there is essentiallu no metal-nitrite association in KNO2 so the oxygen is the main nucleophile.

Comment: thank you! can you please read my comment on the main post and see if I have understood everything correctly?

Answer (score 1):

I will attempt to answer what I think is an underlying question, "How is charge distributed in the nitrite ion?". If this question is answered, then which is the correct structure for silver nitrite between your suggestions will follow.

According to Long and Marsh the oxygen and nitrogen atoms are both about the same distance away from the silver atoms in the solid crystal structure. They refer to the work of Kay and Frazer on sodium nitrite, which has the same crystal structure, wherein they estimate the charges on the atoms of the nitrite anions based on neutron scattering data. The charge estimates for oxygen and nitrogen were -0.32 and -0.36 charge units, respectively. So my best guess is that real life lies about in the middle between your two structures.

As an example or consequence of this "just about even" charge distribution, I will consider a classic named reaction, the Victor Meyer Reaction, wherein silver nitrite is reacted with an alkyl halide (R-X) to form a nitroalkane. Note that in the nitroalkane, the nitrogen has been alkylated: R-NO2. A competing reaction is nitrite ester formation, where the oxygen of the nitrite ion is alkylated: R-ONO. In practice both of these reactions occur, e.g. Plummer and Drake, which is another indication that the charge is distributed similarly between nitrogen and oxygen.

[Long and Marsh, Acta Crystallographica, 15, 448 (1962)](https://doi.org/10.1107/S0365110X62001127)
[Kay and Frazer, Acta Crystallographica, 14, 56, (1961)](https://doi.org/10.1107/S0365110X61000103)
[Plummer and Drake, JACS, 76, 2720 (1954)](https://doi.org/10.1021/ja01639a038)

Answer (score 1):

The crystal structure of silver nitrite has been published at least three times, with different silver nitrogen bond lengths leading to different conclusions:

In the 1981 paper (Structure of silver (I) nitrite, a redetermination, S Ohba and Y Saito, Acta Crystallographica Section B), the abstract reads:

> AgNO2, Mr= 153.9, orthorhombic, Imm2, a= 3.528 (1), b= 6.172 (1), c= 5.181 (1) A, V= 112.8 (1)/~ 3, Z= 2, Dx= 4.53 Mg m-3, g (Ag Ka)= 4.26 mm-k The structure of AgNO2 has been redetermined using a four-circle diffractometer with Ag Ka radiation. The final R value is 0.024 for 1128 observed reflections. The Ag-N distance is 2.304 (2) A, suggesting some covalency in the Ag-N bond. A large anisotropy in the atomic thermal vibrations was found.

So they say it is ionic with some covalency. The discussion of the Ag-N bond without the discussion of the Ag-O bond suggests that nitrogen is the closest neighbor of nitrogen.

The introduction talks a bit about the other two papers:

> The crystal structure of AgNO2 was first determined by Ketelaar (1936) from rotation and powder photographs and it was reinvestigated by Long & Marsh (1962) on the basis of Weissenberg photo-graphs. Covalent radii of Ag and N atoms are 1.34 and 0.74,~, respectively, the sum being 2.08/~. The Ag-N distance derived by Ketelaar was 2.07 (30)] k, indicating complete covalency, whereas Long & Marsh reported it to be 2.47 (8) A, which suggests a primarily ionic bond. It is probable that the Ag-N bond has appreciable covalency because AgNO2 possesses the character of nitro compounds [...]

Neither showing a covalent bond only, or showing just one anion and one cation (instead of the complete crystal structure) does the compound justice. What the data shows, though, is that the nitrogen atom is pretty close to the silver.